# MySQL - problem retriving row comparing string - collate

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I've a table in MySQL 8 "test" with utf8 encoding

```
SELECT CCSA.character_set_name FROM information_schema.`TABLES` T,
       information_schema.`COLLATION_CHARACTER_SET_APPLICABILITY` CCSA
WHERE CCSA.collation_name = T.table_collation
  AND T.table_schema = "test"
  AND T.table_name = "user_login";
```

with two rows than contain values in column "login" the values

```
id login
-- ---
1  uu
2  ùù
```

The select

```
select *, 'explicit utf8_unicode_ci' used_collation from test where login=_utf8'uu' COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
```

return all the two rows. Why? How can i return only the exact result of the where clause?

Comment: Related: [UTF-8 all the way through](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use utf8mb4

```
CREATE TABLE test
    (`id` varchar(2), `login` varchar(3))
;
    
INSERT INTO test
    (`id`, `login`)
VALUES
    ('1', 'uu'),
    ('2', 'ùù')
;
```

```
select *, 'explicit utf8_unicode_ci' used_collation 
  from test where login=_utf8mb4'uu' COLLATE  utf8mb4_0900_as_cs              ;
```

| id | login | used_collation |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | uu | explicit utf8_unicode_ci |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/6tjKgySj)

Answer (score 0):

Declare the collation for the column to be `utf8_bin` or some other `_bin`.  Else, you get "accent insensitive" comparison.  MySQL 8 has `_as_` collations that also provide accent insensitivity.